# Indexing whole Tensor along specific dimension and specific channels

Tags: python, numpy, tensorflow, indexing, pytorch

Let say we have a Tensor **A** with the dimension ***dim(A)=[i, j, k=6, u, v]***. Now we are interested to get the whole tensor at dimension ***k*** with ***channels=[0:3]***. I know we can get it this way:

```
B = A[:, :, 0:3, :, :]
```

Now I would like to know if there is any better "pythonic" way to achieve the same result without doing this suboptimal indexing. I mean something like.

```
B = subset(A, dim=2, index=[0, 1, 2])
```

No matter in which framework, i.e. pytorch, tensorflow, numpy, etc.

Thanks a lot

Comment: `tf.gather` would be unnecessary complex, in your case you would have to build the indices array, for example `tf.gather(A,tf.tile([[[0,1,2]]],[10,10,1]),batch_dims=2)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In numpy, you can use the `take` method:

```
B = A.take([0,1,2], axis=2)
```

---

In TensorFlow, there is not really a more concise way than using the traditionnal approach. Using `tf.slice` would be really verbose:

```
B = tf.slice(A,[0,0,0,0,0],[-1,-1,3,-1,-1])
```

You can potentially use the experimental version of `take` (since TF 2.4):

```
B = tf.experimental.numpy.take(A, [0,1,2], axis=2)
```

---

in PyTorch, you can use `index_select`:

```
torch.index_select(A, dim=2, index=torch.tensor([0,1,2]))
```

---

Note that you can skip listing explicitly the first dimensions (or the last) by using an `ellipsis`:

```
# Both are equivalent in that case
B = A[..., 0:3, :, :]
B = A[:, :, 0:3, ...]
```

Comment: @Thanks a lot, I also found out that in PyTorch "torch.index_select" also does the same thing.

Comment: I'll add it to the answer then. Thanks.